# Set display resolution for official 7" touchscreen display

Tags: display

The official Raspberry Pi display has a resolution of 800x480.

However, Raspbian doesn't have an option for this resolution under Raspberry Pi Confiugration->System-> Set Resolution.

How do I adjust the resolution of the pi to take advantage of exactly 800x480 pixels?

Edit: I should also add, the display setting I have set is 720x480, however, the screen only seems to be displaying a 400 pixel height.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=108&t=184762

and copied below:

> Decided to get an official 7in touch display but instantly figured out
> that 800x480pixel resolution is a little too low for most of my use
> cases (my custom 7in is 1280x800pixels)
>
> Don't know if this has been posted already but you can simple get to
> see some more content on the official display by changing the frame
> buffer size in config.txt I think that 1024x614 pixel is a good trade
> off between quality and achievable resolution (see screen capture
> below).
>
> ```
> cd /boot
> sudo nano config.txt
> ```
>
> and change frame buffer lines to
>
> ```
> #uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
> # overscan.
> framebuffer_width=1024
> framebuffer_height=614 ... reboot and check resolution with
>
>
> fbset -s
> ```

[image: Pi showing it is in 1024x614 resolution]

Comment: This procedure does not work with Pi 4 & the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS. I think because of HDMI hardware changes. Can anyone provide the procedure for newer versions of the hardware/OS?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found and it works for me:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=24679

Just add next row to the end of `/boot/config.txt` This file is also visible from boot disk if you read SD card on your laptop.

```
hdmi_cvt=1680 1050 60 5 0 0 1
```

Reboot.

**Explanation:**

```
hdmi_cvt=<width> <height> <framerate> <aspect> <margins> <interlace> <rb>
width        width in pixels
height       height in pixels
framerate    framerate in Hz
aspect       aspect ratio 1=4:3, 2=14:9, 3=16:9, 4=5:4, 5=16:10, 6=15:9
margins      0=margins disabled, 1=margins enabled
interlace    0=progressive, 1=interlaced
rb           0=normal, 1=reduced blanking
```

The first three arguments are required. The remaining ones are optional. aspect defaults to 16:9 if not specified.